# "Request is missing required authentication credential." when appending API_KEY to Google Sheets API's append

Tags: append, google-sheets-api

I've had success performing get and batchGet operations on my Google Sheet by simply appending ?key={API_KEY} as per the instructions.  BTW, this is being done with jQuery. As far as I understand, this method should work for most Sheet operations, as long as the sheet has no restrictions.
I've read other threads on this subject, and one thread even said that this was "fixed" in 2016.  I need to use the API_KEY URL parameter method because this will be used on kiosks where re-authenticating would be difficult.
Is there some setting I've missed to allow the use of the API_KEY URL parameter for write operations?  Thanks.

ALSO: The live test environment on the https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets.values/append page has an option for using the API_KEY.  I can get this operation to work fine with the Google Auth 2.0 technique, but it fails when using a sample API_KEY (which I suppose makes sense).  No ability here to enter my own API_KEY to try this out?